# I want to run a codeunit automatically in nav2009

Tags: dynamics-nav

I want  a codeunit to run automatically at certain time intervals everyday or once every week.is there any procedure in nav to achieve that?i preferably would not like to run or start nav(from the program files)  for that but without starting nav.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the NAS (Nav Application Server) to achieve this.

I believe in order to set the job up you'll need to fire up the 2009 Classic Client (Rather than the RTC)

You should find the Job Queue in 'Administration' > 'Job Queue'

Once you've defined the job you wish to set up in there configure the NAS accordingly.

You can use the below to install the NAS:

```
nassql.exe appservername=[YourServiceName], 
           NETTYPE=TCP, 
           servername=[YourSqlServer],
           database=[SqlDatabaseName], 
           company="[NavisionCompanyName]", 
           nettype=tcp,
           startupparameter=”[StartUpParam]”, 
           objectcache=40000, 
           installasservice
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: but i don't know the names of appservername,servername,startupparameter and database.how do i find out the above values for my nav server.is there any command or what?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply:

The appservername you can define yourself, this is just what it'll show up as in your running windows services (Run > services.msc) 

The servername is the name of the server your SQL database resides on - same as if you'd do 'File > Database > Open' from the classic client in NAV - use the same server name as you'd select here.

The database name is the database you connect to again - same as if you'd do 'File > Database > Open' use the database name you'd select here.
The startup parameter should be 'JOBQUEUE'

Hope this helps some :)